# Why does JQuery not work for site visitors with read access or site members with Edit access but works for intranet owners with full access?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

On SharePoint online I just finished creating an intranet and each page has a script-editor web app with a jquery script that's used to style summary link controls on the page. The script is also designed to make each group in the summary link control collapsible. The issue is that owners with full access to the site can see the jquery working since they can collapse the summary link groups whereas members and visitors cannot. They can see the summary link control styled but they cannot collapse the individual groups. I think this may be permissions related but I am uncertain. Any advice on the matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if "each" page is checked-in/published. Also, if you referenced any external files in script editor wp ... that files should be checked-in/published as well. Let us know if this helped.

Comment: Using the Site Content and Structure I published a major version of all the site pages. Also no external files are referenced in the script editor wp. I'm still running into the same issue were a visitor / member cannot collapse the groups on the summary links but the site owners can.

Comment: Since this is jQuery feature (collapse the summary link groups ...) look up if jQuery is loaded for this users. Open up console in browser (F12) and try $.fn.jquery or $("div").length ...

Comment: When I use the console command $.fn.jquery when logged in as an owner i get back 1.11.2 where as when logged in as a visitor it shows as fn is undefined.

Comment: Then..jQuery doesn't load for visigor. Check how do you include jQuery to site and if jQuery lib is checked-in if hosted on sharepoint. Let us know if this was the issue.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction in checking on if the Jquery lib is checked in. The site that i created is a sub-site. That being the case the Jquery lib was on the parent site from which i also had access to. Visitor and member on the other hand did not. So what had to be done was to add visitors and members with restricted read permission to the parent site in order for the jquery function to work. This is because the jquery lib is located in the _contents section of the parent site and the sub-sites are inheriting the master page of the parent site.